# time hierarchy does not resolve properly

Tags: mdx, cube

i have a time dimension in the following format Year-> Quarter -> month

but it fails to integrate correct results when doing month vs previous  month

i have tried

```
IIF(
([Measures].[Measures].[Sales Euros],
[v Time3].[KPI Month].CURRENTMEMBER.PARENT)=0,Null,
([Measures].[Sales Euros],
[v Time3].[KPI Month].CURRENTMEMBER)/
([Measures].[Sales Euros],
[v Time3].[KPI Month].CURRENTMEMBER.LAg(1)))
```

actual results
: resolve 2,3, 5,6, 8,9  ,11,12
but not for the first month of each quarter.Any ideas how to solve trough mdx?Thank you

Comment: Can you share what is in the select statement. The above script look fine to me

Comment: Thank you as im using pivot there is no select. i figured i can change the time hierarchy not to include quarter and it works but i need a complex MDX to: for first months only, to go up to the quarter level, get previous quarter, and finally get its last month,

Comment: (upped) interesting question I added an attempt below

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following. 
I've added an extra `IIF` to figure out which month in the quarter you are dealing with:

```
IIF
(
  (
    [Measures].[Measures].[Sales Euros]
   ,[v Time3].[KPI Month].CURRENTMEMBER.PARENT
  ) = 0
, NULL
,
DIVIDE
(  
  (
    [Measures].[Sales Euros]
   ,[v Time3].[KPI Month].CURRENTMEMBER
  )
,
 (
    [Measures].[Sales Euros]
   ,
   //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
   IIF(
      [v Time3].[KPI Month].CURRENTMEMBER.PARENT.FIRSTCHILD
        IS
          [v Time3].[KPI Month].CURRENTMEMBER
      ,[v Time3].[KPI Month].CURRENTMEMBER.PARENT.LAG(1).LASTCHILD
      ,[v Time3].[KPI Month].CURRENTMEMBER.LAG(1)
   )
   //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
)
)
```